# Can't upgrade ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, updates

Try to upgrade ubuntu to 20.04 from 18.04, but software updater doesn't show the upgrade option.
So I tried to do that in command line.

after do the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

get outcome

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

any ideas for that?
Thanks

Comment: The `-d` option means you want the development release.  But 20.04 has already been released.  So, you shouldn't need it.  Can you try removing that option?

Comment: Hey Ray, I tried your method, just got the output

`sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
No new release found.`

can't let it work...

Comment: Good to hear you solved your problem!  If you're interested, you might as well copy your solution into an answer and indicate it is the "answer" so that it "closes" the question.

Comment: @Ray Thanks buddy, but I got another problem that the network-manager is not running, did search online for a while, still not got it :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but since Ubuntu 18.04 (I think), Ubuntu has switched to netplan.  You can still use Network Manager with it, but for servers I look after, I gave up with Network Manager and made it use netplan instead.  Perhaps you can take a look to see if that will help?  See [this](https://netplan.io/) or search for "Ubuntu netplan" and anything will probably be more helpful than me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 15):

Just solve it, it seems like my openssl got problems.  So I follow
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5845
to let the Software Updater work again.

actually, after fixed the SSL, it still shows

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
No new release found.
```

then I found
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-update-upgrade-anymore-um-18-04-v2-lts/19745/3
which edited `/etc/update-manager/meta-release`

```
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release  
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
```

TO

```
http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release  
http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
```

then works well!

Comment: it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

First, enable debug logs:

```
$ DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=1 do-release-upgrade
...
result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)>'
...
```

So in my case, the connection failed due to the certification of the proxy. Then change /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade to ignore this check.

Insert this code at the beginning of /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade file but after the '**future**' line:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

ok, now it works!